# How to parse string having two delimiters in plsql using regex

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a string like "0:1;2:3". 
Columns are separated by colon and Rows are separated by semi-colon.

I am trying to implement a regex that can split the string and then I will use the same for other purposes.

I have written the following code but not sure whats wrong with it. It keeps on executing and then gives out of memory.

I am new to PL/SQL so not sure what wrong. Can someone please suggest.

```
DECLARE
   vfirstpos    NUMBER;
   vsecondpos   NUMBER;
   vkey         VARCHAR2 (32767);
   vvalue       VARCHAR2 (32767);
   vclob        CLOB;                                     
   vgroup       VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
   vclob := '0:1;2:3';

   IF vclob IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      LOOP
         vgroup :=
            REGEXP_SUBSTR (vclob,
                           '[^;]+',
                           1,
                           1);
         BEGIN
            vfirstpos :=
               INSTR (vgroup,
                      ':',
                      1,
                      1);
            vsecondpos :=
               INSTR (vgroup,
                      ':',
                      1,
                      2);

            vkey := (SUBSTR (vgroup, 1, vfirstpos - 1));
            vvalue :=
               (SUBSTR (vgroup, vfirstpos + 1, (vsecondpos - vfirstpos) - 1));
                        vclob := SUBSTR (vclob, LENGTH (vgroup) + 2);
            EXIT WHEN LENGTH (vclob) = 0;
         END;
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

well i solved it by modifying the query. seems like i was splitting it to a third level and that was causing the issue.

changed code

```
DECLARE
   vclob        CLOB;
   vgroup       VARCHAR2 (32767);
   vfirstpos    NUMBER;
   vkey         VARCHAR2 (32767);
   vvalue       VARCHAR2 (32767);  
   vid            number;
BEGIN
    --this should come from an input parameter
   vclob := '1:1;2:hello@hello.com';

   IF vclob IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      LOOP
         vgroup :=
            REGEXP_SUBSTR (vclob,
                           '[^;]+',
                           1,
                           1);
         BEGIN
            vfirstpos :=
               INSTR (vgroup,
                      ':',
                      1,
                      1);
            vkey := (SUBSTR (vgroup, 1, vfirstpos - 1));            
            vvalue :=
               (SUBSTR (vgroup, vfirstpos + 1));  

         END;
         vclob := SUBSTR (vclob, LENGTH (vgroup) + 2);
         EXIT WHEN LENGTH (vclob) = 0;
      END LOOP;
      commit;
   END IF;
END;
```